Applying the Euler Method to problems in Epidemiology
I am learning about how to apply the Euler Method to real world problems.
My understanding of the method is the following . Given an initial value problem:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x, y), \quad y(x_0) = y_0 $$
The Euler method approximates the solution iteratively:
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + h \cdot f(x_n, y_n) $$
Where:

$y_n$ is the approximation of $y$ at $x_n$
$h$ is the step size
$x_{n+1} = x_n + h$

As an example, to solve the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$ with initial condition $y(0) = 1$ using the Euler method.
Assume step size of $h = 0.1$ and calculate the first few steps:

Start: $x_0 = 0$, $y_0 = 1$
Calculate $y_1$:
$$ y_1 = y_0 + h \cdot f(x_0, y_0) = 1 + 0.1 \cdot 1 = 1.1 $$
Calculate $y_2$:
$$ y_2 = y_1 + h \cdot f(x_1, y_1) = 1.1 + 0.1 \cdot 1.1 = 1.21 $$
Calculate $y_3$:
$$ y_3 = y_2 + h \cdot f(x_2, y_2) = 1.21 + 0.1 \cdot 1.21 = 1.331 $$


I am interested in knowing if the Euler Method can be applied to the SIR model in epidemiology.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology)
The basic SIR model is defined by the following system of ordinary differential equations:
$$ \frac{dS}{dt} = -\beta SI $$
$$ \frac{dI}{dt} = \beta SI - \gamma I $$
$$ \frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma I $$
Where:

$S$ is the number of susceptible individuals
$I$ is the number of infected individuals
$R$ is the number of recovered individuals
$\beta$ is the transmission rate
$\gamma$ is the recovery rate

If we assume some step size, we should be able to apply the Euler Method to these equations:
$$ S_{n+1} = S_n + h \cdot (-\beta S_n I_n) $$
$$ I_{n+1} = I_n + h \cdot (\beta S_n I_n - \gamma I_n) $$
$$ R_{n+1} = R_n + h \cdot (\gamma I_n) $$
I tried to create some basic example:

Total population: $N = 1000$
Initial susceptible: $S_0 = 999$
Initial infected: $I_0 = 1$
Initial recovered: $R_0 = 0$
Transmission rate: $\beta = 0.3$
Recovery rate: $\gamma = 0.1$
Time step: $h = 0.1$ days

Then calculate the values at the first few time points:
Step 1:
$$ S_1 = 999 + 0.1 \cdot (-0.3 \cdot 999 \cdot 1) = 969.03 $$
$$ I_1 = 1 + 0.1 \cdot (0.3 \cdot 999 \cdot 1 - 0.1 \cdot 1) = 30.87 $$
$$ R_1 = 0 + 0.1 \cdot (0.1 \cdot 1) = 0.01 $$
Step 2:
$$ S_2 = 969.03 + 0.1 \cdot (-0.3 \cdot 969.03 \cdot 30.87) = 878.33 $$
$$ I_2 = 30.87 + 0.1 \cdot (0.3 \cdot 969.03 \cdot 30.87 - 0.1 \cdot 30.87) = 120.98 $$
$$ R_2 = 0.01 + 0.1 \cdot (0.1 \cdot 30.87) = 0.32 $$
I tried to implement this on a computer (R programming language) and plot the results:


Is my understanding of the mathematics correct?

Looks fine to me. Euler method is basically approximating $y'$ at $x_n$ as $\frac{y_n-y_{n-1}}{h}$

Good work - a note, we need to be careful of stability issues with forward Euler. There are solvers that are a bit more robust if you're open to using out-of-the-box routines (see, e.g. MATLAB's ode45, and in Scipy, scipy.integrate.solve_ivp and scipy.integrate.RK45.)

thank you so much everyone!
